# How to show (for copy&paste) a secret GPG/PGP key without creating a file

Tags: linux, gnupg, pgp, public-key-encryption

I need to access my secret GPG/PGP key to copy/paste it into another application.

How do I show my secret key without generating too much traces of it?

I only know of the export command to gpg (or the export function in several GUI-GPG tools),
but this would always generate a file.
A file on the filesystem needs to be securely erased afterwards, may get picked up by synchronization, backup or mirroring tools etc.

So is there a way to show it in a dialog window (no traces except RAM/swapfile) or at least only to the console window (will leave trace in console history)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `--export` and `--export-secret-keys` write to stdout (which you can pipe wherever you want) if no file is given.

```
gpg --export-secret-keys -a [KEYID]
```

Will output:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.13 (Darwin)
Comment: GPGTools - http://gpgtools.org

[snip]
```

*(ommit the `-a` option if you do not want ascii armored output)*

Comment: Thanks! I was to stupid to actually try the --export option on the command line after all the GUI tools only offered file output.